# How to determine if lat long coordinates are on a road with Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have used Google geo address and using lat/long have got the address. How do I determine if I am on road on not? Basically hit-test for road? I am currently using location manager for lat/long and the GeoAddress is same for on road and next to road.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Final Solution

Use [reverse geocoding via the Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding).

> The term geocoding generally refers to translating a human-readable
>   address into a location on a map. The process of doing the converse,
>   translating a location on the map into a human-readable address, is
>   known as reverse geocoding.
>
> The Geocoding API supports reverse geocoding directly using the latlng
>   parameter. For example, the following query contains the
>   latitude/longitude value for a location in Brooklyn:
>
> ```
> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false
> ```

The docs explain how to interpret the json results but StackOverflow has various answers addressing more efficient ways to parse the data.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8095967/1085891
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8314094/1085891
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6335080/1085891

**Possible Solutions**

- [Getting the nearest street/road coordinates in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607180/getting-the-nearest-street-road-coordinates-in-android) - the answer to this question may point you in the right direction.

  > You can use directions api directly: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=51,19&destination=51,19&sensor=false

  Could you use the API to find directions which would then provide the closest road?
- [Stick position to road on android maps v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700915/stick-position-to-road-on-android-maps-v2)
- [GPSLocator - App to Find Current (Nearest) Location using GPS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112044/GPSLocator-App-to-Find-Current-Nearest-Location-us) - possibly helpful; not so sure on this one.
- [Snap to Roads Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272427/snap-to-roads-android) - Exact same question

**Quick Search Results**

- [Snap to nearest street](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805792/snap-to-nearest-street)
- [Maps API Blog](http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2007_06_01_archive.html) using [GDirections.loadFromWaypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference?csw=1#GDirections)
- [Finding nearest street given a lat-long location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582479/finding-nearest-street-given-a-lat-long-location)
- [Driving route from my location to destination in Google Maps Android API V2](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-route-from-my-location-to-destination-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/)

**Unsolved Similar Questions**

- [Trace the location only on Road in Google maps V2 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724649/trace-the-location-only-on-road-in-google-maps-v2-android)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081417/google-maps-v2-snap-to-road-issue

Comment: @JSuar exactly as Mr.Johnson stated.

Comment: Sorry about that. Updated my answer. If none of these links prove useful, I will delete my answer. Still researching, however.

Comment: @JSuar Thanks again for your time and effort.

Comment: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_snap.htm snaps to nearest road how does it know where the road is ? Its interesting .Can we implement the same on android google maps v2 ?Let me know any workaround.Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @jason That solution relies on [loadFromWaypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference?csw=1#GDirections.loadFromWaypoints). [This SO question provides a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271176/loadfromwaypoints-with-more-than-25-points-using-google-maps-api-v2) to the restrictions placed on the function.

Comment: 40.721171, -74.011178 is the point I have clicked how do I snap to nearest road ? in other words how do I know coordinates or polylines for the nearest road ?

Comment: The links in my answer and previous comment provide code examples. I'd just be reposting their code. Unless you post some of your own code, I can't suggest what exactly you need to do.

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.721171,%20-74.011178&sensor=false .How do I know which is the nearest street? or how do I point it to nearest road?Sorry for not providing more code but I have exact location w.r.t to google maps.Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: how do I snap to nearest road from here . http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.721171,%20-74.011178&sensor=false

Comment: [This documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) explains how to interpret and parse the results you need. I know the final pieces are fuzzy but this looks like it will solve your problem. Pretty cool that this geocoding service is available.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44520/discussion-between-jason-and-jsuar)

Answer (score 4):

[**See fiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/x49xz9Le/)

It can be done so much easier with OSRM (nearest) webservice. Make a GET request like:

```
const url = '//router.project-osrm.org/nearest/v1/driving/';
fetch(url + coord.lon + ',' + coord.lat).then(function(response) { 
  return response.json();
}).then(function(json) {
  if (json.code === 'Ok') {
    console.info(json.waypoints[0].location);
  }
});
```

Which is a road/street coordinate.

References — [Project-OSRM](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md#service-nearest)